# IIS Set-Cookie rewrite rule issues

Tags: iis-10, url-rewrite-module

having an issue with an outbound rewrite rule (see below). I got this working on one website, however it is being partly ignored on the second website (hosted on a different server). So not for all the cookies.  One thing that stands out is that the pages where it gets ignored, there are multiple Set-Cookie headers.

Thanks

```
<rule name="AddSameSiteSecureCookieFlag" stopProcessing="false">
   <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".+" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0};SameSite=None;Secure" />
</rule>
```

Win2016/IIS 10 - ASP.NET v2

Comment: did you try to run the failed request tracing in iis? try to use the pattern (.*) instead of .+ in a rule. if it still does not work then try to run the frt in iis. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules. and the os and .net framework you are using is very old. Support for Windows Server 2008 has ended.

Comment: I suspect you are right.

Comment: We upgraded the servers now to WIN2016 / IIS10. Still, the same issue remains. I wonder if it may be because of another rule which makes friendly URLs for a WFC (api.svc) service hosted in the same folder. 
I experimented with:
* moving the rule to server level
* adding the rule directly to the folder in question
* adding other types of rules (change the Status code to 201) which works on other part of the website except for the bit with the WFC